# Universal Windows Plattform and .net core compatibility

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core

How can i understand this list? ->
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

For example i had create an UWP App and i implement this class:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/send-or-receive-files-with-rfcomm

So if this is supporting in UWP 10.0.16299 then this should be compatible in .net core 2.0?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff Unless your code is in a .NET Standard project, it won't be compatible with .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

No! it's not a certain way to find out is it compatible with .Net Core 2.0 or not. It's depend on the .NET Core package which installed on your UWP application.

You must check the version of **Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform** package in your references of your UWP project, if the version is equal or greater than ***6.0.1*** your UWP project be compatible in .NET Core 2.0 .